# hangman programming: unscrambling words (c programming)

Tags: c

I haven't been coding for long (just 2 months).
My question has to do with the iteration of the counter in loops. Below is my program
with while:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int cnt=0;
int match;
int position;
int tries=0;

char letter;


int main()
{FILE *Difficult= fopen("/GODlvl.txt", "r"); 
    char singl[19];
    if (Difficult==NULL){
        return -1;}

    for(int i = 0; i < rnd1; i++)
        fgets(singl, 21, Difficult);

    int DashN1= strlen(singl); 
    printf("%s", singl);
    for (int i=0; i<DashN1-1; i++)
    {
        singl[i]='_';
        singl[DashN1]='\0';
    }

for (int i=0; i<DashN1; i++) /**it adds an extra character ..possibly a space..**/
{
    printf(" ");
    printf(" %c", singl[i]);
}
do{
scanf(" %c", &letter); 
if(letter==singl[cnt])
{
    match=1;
    position=cnt;
    printf("match found");
}
if (position==cnt)
{
    singl[position]=letter;
    printf(" %s", singl);
}
cnt++;
tries++;
}
while(tries!=8);
}
```

the do loop runs starting from 0, and iterates after every step. The problem with this is with the if conditions; they don't test for any arbitrary element in the char array (singl). How can i edit this code(whether the if conditions or the loop) to run for arbitrary index.

Comment: on the line with `for(int i = 0; i < rnd1; i++)` where this `rnd1` is defined? and where it gets its value?.

Comment: It also seems to me that in the first `for` loop the string stored on `singl` array get overwritten in every iteration, is this the desired behavior?

Comment: srand(time(NULL));
    int lowerlimit1 = 1, upperlimit1 = 41;
    int rnd1 = lowerlimit1 + rand() % (upperlimit1 - lowerlimit1);/**end of random**/

Comment: that's for rnd1; upperlimit is the number of words in file or 'lines' if you will.
you're observation for the for loop is correct.  I have tried simply just printing "_" for each element in the array, which is where i have a problem. You see, I can't figure out how to replace each "_" for a letter, while still representing each unguessed letter as "_". I have thought about creating another array, comparing  and replacing the letters but I do not know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the user input for **letter**, you can request a random index for use in `singl`, just by doing:

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
cnt = rand() % DashN1;
```

This means that your do loop, should look like:

```
do{
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    cnt = rand() % DashN1;
    if(letter==singl[cnt]){
      //....
    }
}while(/*...*/);
```

Make sure that you do:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

in order to access `srand` and `rand`

Comment: thank you for this. However, the behaviour of this code has similar issues as my last. I should clarify that my issue was getting this condition " if(letter==singl[cnt]) " to check for every index. The random code works perfectly, thank you, but the main problem remains: if user input is not the same for the index, even if it is in the array, it does not count as a match. for example
word: array
letter=y 
index cnt is on=2 single[2]='r'. y!=2